# How can I find out when a certain program has been running on my computer?

Tags: windows

I need to be logging hours for when I'm working on a school project, and I've fallen off the ball for a few weeks.  I'm hoping there's some sort of event log in Windows (8.1) that I can parse to get the times/timespans that either Visual Studio or Android Studio were open.  Can this be done?

I have zero experience with the Events Viewer, so please either be patient with questions or keep things at a very basic level.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: funnily enough ardamax keylogger is good for that though not free and not designed for that! http://www.ardamax.com/keylogger/

Comment: It's a bit late for that - unless the program itself generates a log, the default config will not log every program launch. You'd have to set something up before you started.

Comment: Damn.  I guess I'll infer everything from Git logs, then.

Answer (score 0):

FileSystemWatcher might be part of a solution. An application (interactive, service, etc.) can register a FileSystemWatcher to receive notifications when folders are accessed; these notifications identify the files and type of access. If your time logger app watches the folder containing Visual Studio, you should get notifications when the IDE is launched, but may not get notification when it is closed (nothing should be updated). However, if you watch your VS solution folder, you should get notifications when the solution is opened, and should also get notifications when the solution is closed, due to updates of the SUO file. The tricky part will be matching/filtering events to get effective/reliable start and end times.